# How to add a new dynamic row within a row using jquery Ajax in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have list of data in a row of tables and added a details action link.

When I click on details link of a row than get another list of data for particular clicked row.

So now I want to add another row with another table with list of rows data below clicked row.

Jquery code:

```
function project_list(id)
{
    var row_ID = 'row'+id;
    $.ajax({
      url : '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/project_list',
      type : 'post',
      data : 'id='+id
    }).done(function (data){
      alert(data);
       $('#'+row_ID).after(data);
    });
    console.log(row_ID); 
}
```

Html Code:

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $item) {?>
 <a href="#" onClick="project_list('<?=$item->ID;?>')">Projects</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Codeigniter Code:

```
function project_list()
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $project_list = $this->admin_model->project_list($id);
        if(is_array($project_list)){
            $i=1;
            $table .= '<tr colspan=7><div><table><thead><tr><th>SN</th><th>Project Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
            foreach($project_list as $row)
            {
                $table .="<tr><td>$i</td><td>$row->project_name</tr>";
                $i++;
            }
            $table .='</tbody></table></div></tr>';
            echo $table;
        }   
    }
```

New Row is Successfully added after click on particular clicked row But issue is table and it's header part is not showing and even div not showing.

Right Now i got this output:

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>PHP</td></tr>
```

But Output will be:

```
    <tr colspan=2>
<div>
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>SN</th><th>Project Name</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>PHP</td></tr>
</tbody></table></div></tr>
```

Comment: Try to add the output `within` TR instead of `after` TR.

Comment: I want to add after TR

Comment: after initializing $i = 1; in your function Remove " . " to append data in $table for the first time...!

Comment: i did but nothing new happen

Comment: Oh why are you using <tr> directly without using table tag?!Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `<td>` after `<tr>`.

Also Apply colspan on `<td>` instead of `<tr>` in PHP code.

```
$table .= '<tr class="dynamicAddedTr"><td colspan=2><div><table><thead><tr><th>SN</th><th>Project Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
            foreach($project_list as $row)
            {
                $table .="<tr><td>$i</td><td>$row->project_name</tr>";
                $i++;
            }
            $table .='</tbody></table></div></td></tr>';
```

To replace the content every time you click on `<tr>` instead of appending, you can give a custom class to dynamic `<tr>` and on click just check if `<tr>` with specific class is exists or not. If yes remove that and add add new content.

> Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/go03oj39/1/ with static data in
>   JS.

Comment: your answer is right and it works but i have another issue when i click any row it adds another table but when i again click on that row then it show same data with twice table and it add more and more table until i click on that row.
But i want when i click on row table added and again i click on that row table override with new table.